# applying various line widths to repetitive segmented diagonal lines in one canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, javascript-objects

i have written code for a canvas measuring 1000 by 800 px.
first i applied a lineair gradient which works properly.
subsequently i wrote code to apply diagonal lines in repetitive segments with a little javascript which also works fine, because i want to change/manipulate the line width per segment i adjust the x and y coordinates accordingly per segment.
unfortunately the line width changes i tried to apply do not work or render properly as i expect them to, i try to alter or manipulate the segments by applying various line width in the range 0,1,2 however most segments show the same line width.

following is my html code the resulting page shows you an html page starting with an image which i try to draw in canvas underneath is my result or you can view the jpg on milton-chocolate.nl to see what i m trying to accomplish in canvas.

furthermore there is a stylesheet connected but i have not entered anything in there yet.

if someone can be so kind to look at my code and if possible solve my line width issue ?

kind regards spalburg

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head><link type ="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/><title>Milton-Chocolate.nl</title></head><body style="background-color: #3c1007; text-align: center
    "><img src = "130418-MC.jpg">
        <br>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="800" style="border: 0px"></canvas>
<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    // Create gradient
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,1000,800);
    grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
    grd.addColorStop(1,"magenta");
    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,1000,800);
    </script>

<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 2;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 50);
        cx.lineTo(40+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>

<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 1;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 100);
        cx.lineTo(80+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>

<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 150);
        cx.lineTo(120+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>

<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 1;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 200);
        cx.lineTo(160+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>

<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.LineWidth = 2;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 250);
        cx.lineTo(200+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 300);
        cx.lineTo(240+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 350);
        cx.lineTo(280+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 400);
        cx.lineTo(320+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 450);
        cx.lineTo(360+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 500);
        cx.lineTo(400+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 550);
        cx.lineTo(440+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 600);
        cx.lineTo(480+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 650);
        cx.lineTo(520+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 700);
        cx.lineTo(560+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 750);
        cx.lineTo(600+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("Canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.lineWidth = 0;
    for (var i = -60; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        cx.moveTo(0+i, 800);
        cx.lineTo(640+i, 0);
    }
cx.stroke();
    </script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, try to re-use code, e.g. by defining functions.

Your problem is that `beginPath` and `stroke` are only executed once for all lines. Instead, you need to do so for each single line, since `lineWidth` was updated.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/507vmLuj/2/) implementing that (I changed colors line thickness a bit to make the effect more visible).

Comment: Cedric thanks for your beautiful and elegant code, I fiddled a bit with the moveTo an lineTo to make the lines more similar to the JPG

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting and upvoting my answer if the issue is cleared for you.

Comment: Cedric i presume i select the votes tab and the answer your question button? (bit of a newbie) of course this answer is answered, but if i have another one concerning this project ?

Comment: If you will put your fiddle into a stackoverflow snippet (or paste the code directly into your answer) and then ping me, I would consider upvoting your answer. Fiddle-dependent answers are considered too fragile to be the only code in your answer. ;-)

Comment: hmm i can't up vote first need 15 reputation before i can change the public display post score.... humbug